# Web Api не может конвертнуть объект Entity для формирования которого использовался Eager loading в Json

Tags: c#, json, webapi

есть Модель  EF :

```
public partial class Brunch
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Brunch()
    {
        this.Orders = new HashSet<Orders>();
        this.Staff = new HashSet<Staff>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Staff> Staff { get; set; }
}
```

Также есть репозиторий:

```
public class BrunchRepository : IRepository<Brunch>
{
   private  DbSet<Brunch> _db;
    public BrunchRepository(MVCEntities context)
    {
       this._db = context.Brunch;
    }


    public void Add(Brunch item)
    {
        _db.Add(item);
    }

    public Brunch FindById(int id)
    {
      return  _db.Where(x => x.Id == id).Include(x => x.Orders).First();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Brunch> GetAll()
    {
        return _db.Include(x=>x.Orders).Include(x=>x.Staff).ToList(); 
    }

    public void Remove(Brunch item)
    {
        _db.Remove(item);
    }


}
```

С этим репозиторием работает Unit Of Work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private MVCEntities _context = new MVCEntities();
    public BrunchRepository brunchRepository;


    public BrunchRepository Brunches
    {
        get {
            if (brunchRepository == null)
                brunchRepository = new BrunchRepository(_context);
            return brunchRepository;
        }
    }




    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (_context != null)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
            _context = null;
        }
    }



    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Обращение к UnitOfWork происходит в сервисе:

```
public class BrunchService : IService<Brunch>
{
    public IEnumerable<Brunch> GetAll()
    {
       IEnumerable<Brunch> x = new  List<Brunch>();

        try
        {
            using (UnitOfWork unit = new UnitOfWork())
            {

               x= unit.Brunches.GetAll();

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return x;

    }

}
```

Сервис уже вызывается в контроллере:

```
public class BrunchController : ApiController
{
    BrunchService service = new BrunchService();
    // GET: api/Brunch
    public IEnumerable<Brunch> Get()
    {
        var x = service.GetAll();

        return x;
    }
```

В файле Global.asax.cs добавлены следующие строки:

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

При обращении к api/Brunch браузер выдает следующее:

"Message":"Произошла ошибка.","ExceptionMessage":"Типу \"ObjectContent`1\" не удалось сериализовать текст ответа для типа содержимого \"application/json; charset=utf-8\".","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"Произошла ошибка.","ExceptionMessage":"Self referencing loop detected for property 'Brunch' with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Brunch_15800F995AD87D31FD3C76D3D502A42DCAB829CB24221E86D0280A91B157B410'. Path '[0].Orders[0]'.","ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException","StackTrace":"

Comment: Пожалуйста, приложите код текстом, а не картинкой. Добавил минус вопросу за плохое оформление.

Comment: Вас понял, исправлю в ближайшее время

Comment: Ок, жду. И ещё, у вас опечатка в названии сущности - Branch.

Comment: Исправил, надеюсь  правильно описал суть проблемы

Comment: Модели EF не предназначены для того, чтобы их сериализовать. Вам нужно использовать Dto-объекты, которые не будут содержать ссылок на сущности. Конкретно здесь и сейчас ошибка возникает от того, что у вас объекты получаются в циклических ссылках.

Comment: Большое спасибо, пойду править.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно здесь и сейчас ошибка возникает от того, что у вас объекты получаются в циклических ссылках. Но нужно править не здесь, пытаясь разорвать ссылку, а этажом выше.

Модели EF не предназначены для того, чтобы их сериализовать. Вам нужно использовать Dto-объекты, которые не будут содержать ссылок на сущности.

Создайте BrunchDto:

```
public partial class BrunchDto
{
    public BrunchDto(Brunch entity)
    {
        this.Id = entity.Id;
        this.Address = entity.Address;
        this.Name = entity.Name;
        this.Email = entity.Email;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

И сериализуйте её:

```
// GET: api/Brunch
public IEnumerable<Brunch> Get()
{
    var x = service.GetAll().Select(e => new BrunchDto(e));

    return x;
}
```